# google maps autocomplete bounds not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I want to use autocomplete bounds on Google maps service. But not working.

```
//----autocomplete start
var input = (document.getElementById('searchPlace'));
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(40.518, 29.215),
            new google.maps.LatLng(41.242, 30.370));

var options = {
            bounds:defaultBounds,
            componentRestrictions: { country: 'XX'},};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
//----autocomplete end
```

When I type the textbox, the addresses are coming in XX country. But I wanna restrict the search in a region of country. For example a city bounds. But other addresses are coming out of this bounds. Bounds are not considered.

Comment: [From the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) : The results are biased towards, **but not restricted to**, Places contained within these bounds.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds) expects south-west and north-east corners. Also referred as bottom-left and top-right corners.

Instead of:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.518, 29.215),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.242, 30.370));
```

It should be:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.242, 29.215),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.518, 30.370));
```

Comment: this is still right as of 2018. south-east x north-west won't cut it.

Comment: also add strictBounds:true to the options

Answer (score 2):

**Updated 10/2018: this answer is obsolete; please see other answers**

It will not work as you wish. This is what documentation says:

> The area in which to search for places. Results are biased towards,
>   but not restricted to, places contained within these bounds.

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.13/reference#AutocompleteOptions)

Comment: The link above seems to be broken. Alternative URL will be https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms.

Comment: Now they have added a new boolean parameter called "strictBounds". If set to true, the API does not return results outside this region even if they match the user input.

Answer (score 1):

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(17.2916377 ,78.2387067),
                new google.maps.LatLng(17.5608321, 78.6223912)
);

var input = document.getElementById('destination');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['establishment'],
  strictBounds: true
};

var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you are using bounds you cannot use componentRestrictions...

Try this..

```
    //----autocomplete start
    var input = (document.getElementById('searchPlace'));
    var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.518, 29.215),
        new google.maps.LatLng(41.242, 30.370));

    var options = {
        bounds:defaultBounds
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    //----autocomplete end
```

Answer (score -2):

Bounds only works for the maps API, not the Places API.

For [location biasing](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete?csw=1#location_biasing) in the Places API you need to use a location latlng object and a radius (in meters) in the options.

```
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.9907,-84.0497);

        var acOptions = {
            location: myLatlng,
            radius: 150000,  // (in meters; this is 150Km)
            types: ['address'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
        };
```

Note that this *only biases* the autocomplete results to the radius you entered; it does *not restrict* the results to that radius.

Comment: I get `TypeError: a.lat is not a function` when trying that method. Why do they document Bounds on the places API if it doesn't support it?

Comment: Yes, I am also had impression that Places API doesn't support bounds, according to their doc. However it really support.  Just specify "bounds" property in options, and find address only within specified bounds.